# Stata: handling variable label containing protected character

Tags: stata

I'm working with about a hundred Stata data files imported from SPSS files to which I no longer have access. In building a summary description across all files I'm documenting the variable and value labels, which includes loops such as this:

```
foreach v of varlist _all {
   local varlbl: variable label `v'
   // do some more things
   file write `outfile' `"`v'"' // and some other stuff
}
```

This is fine nearly all the time and the additional backtick and single quote properly escape more common semiproblematic stuff such as inline quotes in variable labels.

What breaks it is a label like this:

```
BC9C            str1    %-1s       BC9C       See/hear ACT: `Newspaper
```

Here it can't handle the inline backtick just prior to `Newspaper`. I've tried the following to deal with this issue, all except #5 being trivially different from one another:

1. Remove the offending character *(fails w/ 'too few quotes')*:

   ```
   newlbl = subinstr(`"`varlbl'"',`"`"',"",.)
   newlbl = subinstr(`"`varlbl'"',`"`"',"",.) // escaping doesn't help, either
   ```
2. If the character is present, do something else *(fails w/ 'too few quotes')*:

   if strpos(`"`varlbl'"',`"`"')>0 {
       // something else
   }
3. Substitute a local to represent the backtick *(fails and silly in this case)*:

   ```
   local bt `"`"'
   local newlbl = subinstr(`"`varlbl'"',`"`bt'"',"",.)
   ```
4. Use -regexr- because maybe it's somehow more robust *(fails w/ 'too few quotes')*:

   ```
   local varlbl = regexr(`"`varlbl'"',"`","")
   ```
5. Export to either plain text or XML and use another language to find/replace, using `xmlsave` or `outfile, dictionary`. *This works but is a painful workaround.*

Because these backticks are pure nuisance, removing them is sufficient. Thanks for reading, considering and any feedback. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's an approach that better matches the problem. I've spent no effort exploring ways to make it more elegant. The key is the use of the macro extended function `subinstr` rather than using the non-macro function `subinstr()`.

```
. describe x

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x               float   %9.0g                 junk with `backtick

. local xl : variable label x

. local b `"`"'

. local xl2 : subinstr local xl "`b'" ""

. display "`xl2'"
junk with backtick

.
```

Comment: Indeed, this does it brilliantly. Many thanks. Do you know whether tolerance for inline protected characters is a general property of the macro extended functions?

Comment: I cannot give a documented confirmation, but that is my belief. The existence of a syntax that allows the user to avoid expanding the macro suggests to me that the extended string function directly accesses the stored macro string, allowing it to ignore the meaning of special characters. The common caveat that `\0` is not an allowed character when using a macro extended string function also suggests that direct access to the string is used.

Comment: I note, reviewing your past posts, that you perhaps are unaware of the possibility of accepting an answer to your question when it has worked to your satisfaction. [http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) But in any event, I'm glad to have been of help, even if it took me two tries to get it right!

Comment: That's a safe inference, but in this case I lost connectivity before ticking the 'check' mark. Now, on the ground again, I'm very glad to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. I used two generate statements to show details, `char(96)` could be used as the second argument to `subinstr()`.

```
. clear

. input str30 lbl

                                lbl
  1. "See/hear ACT: `Newspaper"
  2. end

. generate from = char(96)

. generate lbl2 = subinstr(lbl,from,"",.)

. list, clean noobs

                         lbl   from                      lbl2  
    See/hear ACT: `Newspaper      `   See/hear ACT: Newspaper  

.
```

Comment: Good, but `generate lbl2 = subinstr(lbl, char(96), "", .)` avoids putting the same constant character in a new variable without lasting interest or use.

Comment: Nick, did you miss my explanation for using two generate statements in the intro preceding the quoted code? My intent was to visibly demonstrate that `char(96)` yields a string containing a single backquote.

Comment: Fine. A user new to the device should want to do it the long way round first.

Comment: These suggestions answer the very useful questions (a) How does one address a character code in Stata and (b) what is the Stata character code for a backtick?

Unfortunately, where the label is already given it doesn't work. Given the label *Source of Antibiotic: ``Private Mobile / Outreach clinic* , 

`gen from = char(96)`

`- local varlbl = subinstr(``"``varlbl'"',from,"",.)`

`= local varlbl = subinstr(``"Source of Antibiotic: ,from,"",.)`

The backtick is still parsed. I've tried the same approach with -regexm-, with the same result.

Comment: I spent more than my allotted 5 minutes trying to get the mini-markdown correct, so I'm locked out of my previous comment.

Given the label *Source of Antibiotic: ``Private Mobile / Outreach clinic* ,  and using `gen from = char(96)`, `- local varlbl = subinstr(``"``varlbl'"',from,"",.)` gets executed as `= local varlbl = subinstr(``"Source of Antibiotic: ,from,"",.)` and the backtick is still parsed. I've tried -regexm-, with the same result.

Comment: I'd hoped that referencing the local with `gen` would solve it, a la `gen varlbl = ``"``varlbl'"'` , (there are double backticks showing because I'm not clever enough to to escape them with mini-markdown) but this suffers the same problem (again, too few quotes).

Comment: If the problem is that Stata recursively examines a macro from the inside out, and an unescaped backtick followed by a character evaluate-able as a local leads Stata to look for its matching single quote, a variant on `-display-'s` 'asis' argument or `macval()` could do the trick. Indeed, both 'asis' and 'macval()' allow `-display-` to display the problematic string. However, I've been unable to find an equivalent option for string manipulation and `-display-' doesn't store its result (nor would doing so necessarily help in this case).

Comment: I'll mention a wrinkle I encountered while processing a label. This particular label is "economic advantages\`", where the backtick is the final character. Stata expands this to
      `= mata: __000002=__000002\(\`"economic advantages\`"', modify"')` , which leads it to throw **mismatched quotes**. Seems an easy solution is appending a sacrificial character to the local so that the backtick character is not longer final, but I've yet to figure out how to do this without encountering the problems in my original post.